# how to launch Sketch Up via wine

Tags: wine

I'm trying to install google sketchup make via wine, the installation is successful but when I click to launch sketchup nothing happens, just nothing...

wine: 1.7
ubuntu: 14.04
sketch up :2015

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

You just install `playonlinux` via Software Center.

Then search for `SketchUp` in `playonlinux` and just follow the installation procedure...